# How to set Google Cloud Storage ACLs with gcloud-node?

Tags: gcloud-node

The library was announced recently, which is much simpler to use than the old google apis client http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.jp/2014/09/gcloud-node-google-cloud-platform-client-library-for-nodejs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set them with the ACL meta data as follows:

```
bucket.createWriteStream(filename, {
        'acl': [
          {
            "entity": "allUsers",
            "role": "READER"
          }
        ]
      });
```

This will set a object to public.